# null or empty vs no param - calling API with optional parameters

Tags: javascript, api, rest

Is there any preferable way? What's the normal out there when it comes to optional params?

- Send all parameters with `null` or empty string values
- Or just call the API without them?

All values are being sent:

```
var params{
    param1: 'demo',
    param2: null,
    param3: 'demo',
    param4: null,
    param5: '',
    param6: 'demo',
    param7: 'demo'
}

$.get(apiURL, params, function(data){
    //response
});
```

Only the necessary values are being sent:

```
var param2 = {
    paramName: 'param2',
    value: null
};
var param4 = {
    paramName: 'param4',
    value: null
};
var param5 = {
    paramName: 'param5',
    value: ''
};

var params{
    param1: 'demo',
    param3: 'demo',
    param6: 'demo',
    param8: 'demo'
};

//adding params if they have a value
var optionalValues = [param2, param4, param5];
optionalValues.forEach(function(optionalParam) {

    //not null or empty?
    if(optionalParam.value && optionalParam.value.length){
        var param = {};
        param[optionalParm.paramname] = optionalParam.value;
        params.push(param);
    }
});

$.get(url, params, function(data){
    //response
});
```

As the API service might be logging all parameters it gets, it seems sending unnecessary information can increase the size of logs and even make them more difficult to read if receiving unnecessary information.

Comment: Missing `=` here `var params{`. Can you explain what is happening

Comment: `Object.assign(params, param2, param4, param5);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. JavaScript can do this.

```
var params = {
    param1: 'demo',
    param2: null,
    param3: 'demo',
    param4: null,
    param5: '',
    param6: 'demo',
    param7: 'demo'
}
for(x in params) { if(params[x] === undefined || params[x] === null || params[x] === '') { delete params [x]; } }
console.log(params);

$.get(url, params, function(data){
    //response
});
```

But I recommend use '[lodash](https://lodash.com/)' or '[underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)' for more fun!

```
_.pickBy(params) // pick param1, 3, 6 and 7 :)

$.get(url, _.pickBy(params), function(data){
    //response
});
```